# SQL reordering the alphanumeric values of a column and updating the missing number in a sequence order

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a challenging situation. I have to reorder the values of a column which is having alphanumeric value. I have to identify the missing numbers and have to update with natural order.

Scenario:
Select * from Persons;

```
id  lastname firsstname Country City       EmployeeCode

1   Maddy   unknown     India   Bangalore  ABC001
2   Sun     Moon        Earth   Solar      ABC002
3   Tiger   Mr          Zoo     Forest     ABC010
4   Flower  Sun         Garden  Park       ABC015
```

In the above table, For the column Employee code I have to identify the missing order like ABC003 to ABC009 is missing. And I have to update it in ordered [Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQm7G.jpg) [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlejQ.jpg)sequence as shown below:

```
id  lastname firsstname Country City       EmployeeCode
1   Maddy   unknown     India   Bangalore  ABC001
2   Sun     Moon        Earth   Solar      ABC002
3   Tiger   Mr          Zoo     Forest     ABC003
4   Flower  Sun         Garden  Park       ABC004
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Why? This is a pretty useless requirement; there is no reason for employee codes to be "in natural order". This is a very common question on Stack Overflow; it reflects a poor understanding of the purpose of such codes. What are you supposed to do - whenever rows are added, deleted, or updated, run another update to put employee codes back in "natural order"? To what end?

Comment: This is just a sample. Actually we have 100k plus records where due to some sequence issue caused the discontinuity of record numbering. In the process of identifying those missing numbers and we have to order it.

Comment: Why? Why do you have to "order" it (by which I assume you mean "eliminate the gaps")? It doesn't matter if you have 500 rows (records?) or 100k - what difference does it make? Why are you (your organization, your team) averse to discontinuity in "record" numbering? Any code or decision or report that depends on "continuity" of numbering in employee codes is total nonsense. What do you **need** it for?

Comment: I agree with the others. This seems like a useless thing to do. Especially if that "employeecode" is used in other things (outside of the database) like the employee's contract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use this update if the id column is sequential:

```
UPDATE persons p
SET EmployeeCode = 'ABC' || LPAD(id, 3, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this update statement:

```
UPDATE persons p
SET EmployeeCode = 'ABC' || LPAD(ROWNUM, 3, '0');
```

Comment: Won't the order be random though? There is no particular order in which the rows are retrieved (and therefore assigned a `rownum`).

Comment: The OP suggested (in the question) that the ordering needs to be by the column that is being updated. It is not clear what the ID column does (indeed, why there is an ID column as well as an employee code). Also, it is not clear why - in the OP's example - the employee codes are out of whack, but the ID's are still in a nice, natural "order".

Comment: Another suggestion: To format a number by LPADding with zeros, you don't need LPAD (which still converts the number to characters implicitly, a poor practice). You could use `to_char(number, '009')` instead. This takes care of leading zeros at the same time it converts the number to string.